# Is there an RSS feed available for Twitter notifications?

Tags: twitter, rss

I would like to feed all updates to the Twitter notification tab into a daily digest of my email RSS feed reader. Is there a RSS feed available for new Twitter notifications?

[image: Twitter notification tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not anymore. According to [this official blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/api-v1-retirement-final-dates), all RSS feeds that were provided by Twitter in the past were deprecated in 2013.

> - JSON is API v1.1’s only output format. XML, RSS, and ATOM response formats will be retired along with API v1.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=xxxxx works for me, replace the xxxxx with your twitter ID/username.

Comment: I receive the following error: `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.`